# Add a row for displaying total balance at the end of the grid Magento Admin GiftCardAccount

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

In the magento admin control panel,

Customers = > GiftCardAccounts

I want to display the total of Balance as a row just below the grid . 
I tried to set `$this->setCountTotals(true);` in the method `public function __construct()` in the Grid.php, but it didn't worked.
Please let me know how to do this exactly. Any help would be greatly  appreciated.

Comment: why this is not answered yet ?

Comment: the answer bellow is a correct one, please mark it as the answer and vote it up!

Answer (score 2):

I came across yours as I was searching for an answer to this for myself. I find it interesting that this seems to be a non-existant topic of discussion online - maybe everyone has it already figured out?

Here is what you will need to do:

In `etc/config.xml` of your module, override the block like so:

```
<blocks>
    <enterprise_giftcardaccount>
        <rewrite>
            <adminhtml_giftcardaccount_grid>Namespace_Giftcardaccount_Adminhtml_Giftcardaccount_Grid</adminhtml_giftcardaccount_grid> <!-- I like to put overrides/rewrites in their same folder under my namespace -->
        </rewrite>
    </enterprise_giftcardaccount>
</blocks>
```

Now, in Namespace/Giftcardaccount/Block/Adminhtml/Giftcardaccount/Grid.php, do this:

```
<?php

class Namespace_Giftcardaccount_Adminhtml_Giftcardaccount_Grid extends Enterprise_GiftCardAccount_Block_Adminhtml_Giftcardaccount_Grid {

    protected function _prepareGrid()
    {
        $collection = $this->getCollection();

        $balanceTotal = 0;
        foreach ($collection as $giftCardAccount) {
            $balanceTotal += $giftCardAccount->getBalance();
        }

        $this->setTotals(new Varien_Object(
            array(
                'balance' => $balanceTotal
            )
        );

        $this->setCountTotals(true);

        return parent::_prepareGrid();
    }

}
```

That should do it!

Comment: Thank you man, you saved me a time! I corrected some syntax errors, and you have missed the parent method call.

Comment: Actually, just for your reference, it is correct in it's original form. Chances are, `parent::_prepareGrid` is returning `$this`. I would suggest studying up on the grid component in Magento.

Comment: The problem is that the $this->getCollection() is null until you call the parent::_prepareGrid(), at least in my version of magento 1.7